# Extract part of URL in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(urls = c("/players/a/abdulma02.html", 
"/players/a/abdulta01.html", 
"/players/a/abdursh01.html", "/players/a/alexaco01.html", "/players/a/alexaco02.html"
), names = c("Mahmoud Abdul-Rauf", "Tariq Abdul-Wahad", "Shareef Abdur-Rahim", 
"Cory Alexander", "Courtney Alexander")), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")

head(mydf)
                       urls               names
1 /players/a/abdulma02.html  Mahmoud Abdul-Rauf
2 /players/a/abdulta01.html   Tariq Abdul-Wahad
3 /players/a/abdursh01.html Shareef Abdur-Rahim
4 /players/a/alexaco01.html      Cory Alexander
5 /players/a/alexaco02.html  Courtney Alexander
```

My problem is simple - I would like to extract the part of the url before the html (abdulma02, abdulta01, etc.). The data is formatted such that the ending will always be `.html`, and the start will always be `/players/{single letter}/{what i want}.html`

I have taken a stab at this using the new `urltools` library to no success (tried their `urltools::suffix_extract()` function). Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(mydf$urls))
#[1] "abdulma02" "abdulta01" "abdursh01" "alexaco01" "alexaco02"
```

Comment: gotta bookmark this post - greatly appreciated @akrun